# rbt tool - aborts due to missing http authorization

Tags: mercurial, review-board, rbtools

I'm using Mercurial and somehow rbt tools fail to run `rbt diff` on the repository because of missing http authorization

below is the error I get
`Failed to execute command: [u'hg', u'-q', u'outgoing', u'--template', u'{rev}\\t
{node|short}\\t{branch}\\n', u'default', u'-r', u'.']
abort: http authorization required for http://abc.xyz.com/hg/foo/com.my.repository/`

I tried giving the `--username` and `--password`, but they are for review board, not for repository. How can i give credentials for Mercurial repository and gain access?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. Apparently, i need to enable Mercurial Keyring for the repository to allow access to it.